# How to find which Lines and Arcs are connected when imported from DXF?

Tags: python, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I am using [`ezdxf`](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to import a `.dxf` file into Python. It works smoothly. I get a list of lines and arcs.

How do I figure out which lines and arcs are connected to each other? Are they somehow indexed or do I need to search start and end points of lines and arcs and match them afterwards?

What I need to find are the closed lines in the `.dxf` file.

Comment: There is no index built-in index. You need to build that yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to match line and arc end points manually.

Get the end points of arcs with default extrusion (0, 0, 1):

```
from ezdxf.math import Vector

start_point = Vector.from_deg_angle(arc.dxf.start_angle, arc.dxf.radius)
end_point = Vector.from_deg_angle(arc.dxf.end_angle, arc.dxf.radius)
```

Add to arc center:

```
s = start_point + arc.dxf.center
e = end_point + arc.dxf.center
```

If the Object Coordinate System (OCS) defined by `arc.dxf.extrusion` is different from (0, 0, 1), a transformation to the World Coordinate System (WCS) has to be done:

```
ocs = arc.ocs()
s = ocs.to_wcs(s)
e = ocs.to_wcs(e)
```

Next ezdxf version v0.11 will have `Arc.start_point` and `Arc.end_point` properties, which will return the WCS coordinates.

Important: Don't compare with the equal operator (==), use `math.isclose()` or better `Vector.isclose()` like:

```
s.isclose(line.dxf.start, abs_tol=1e-6)
e.isclose(line.dxf.start, abs_tol=1e-6)
s.isclose(line.dxf.end, abs_tol=1e-6)
e.isclose(line.dxf.end, abs_tol=1e-6)
```

Set absolute tolerance according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks very helpful